# How to get data from ruby on rails using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, database, ruby-on-rails-5

i'm trying to grab data from ruby on rails using javascript

You can grab all instances from a database on rails using this

```
@ingredients = current_user.ingredients
```

I would like to use that with the following

```
<%= form.label :name, class: "col-lg-2 control-label" %>
<%= form.text_field :name, id: :autocomplete %>

<script>
  var data = [ "vanilla", "chocolate", "oatmeal", "malt", "citrus", "grape", "cherry" ];
  $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: data });
</script>
```

To get this as the end result

```
<%= form.label :name, class: "col-lg-2 control-label" %>
<%= form.text_field :name, id: :autocomplete %>

<script>
#****************************
  var data = current_user.ingredients
#****************************
  $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: data });
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: It appears as though you're using jQuery UI's autocomplete. If so, [the documentation has an example of getting data from a remove server](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few choices here. You can either

1. **Fetch the autocomplete data via AJAX:**

   To do so, you have to implement an action that returns `current_user.ingredients` as JSON.
2. **Pipe your data into an invisible element in your template:**

   If the data is pretty much static, i.e. doesn’t change between page refreshes, you could use your template to do something along the lines of this:

   ```
   <script>
     var data = <%= current_user.ingredients.to_s %>
   </script>
   ```

---

**Option 1 is the much cleaner approach and I would recommend it** in every aspect, while Option 2 is something that is simple, but will not help you grow as a developer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know you could know about this methods. I just found out you can be super lazy and install GON gem